# Inserting null values into DB when nothing is selected in a DDL

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am inserting values from a dropdownlist into a DB. If nothing is selected I want to enter a null but if nothing is selected z-SELECT- this option not inserted into the DB. 
So how to enter null values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create one more option in select with value NULL.

```
<select>
 <option value="NULL">-SELECT-</option>
</select>
```

Comment: it will send a string with value 'NULL'.

Answer (score 0):

Check the value of the select box before inserting it to DB. you might need to do something like this `

```
if(postedSelectValue=="-SELECT-")

              {
                 //set value to null
                 postedSlectValue=null;
              }
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are not setting a datasource to the dropdownlist (in that case you would be casting the selected item to the type you have set in the datasource and if none is selected, the casting operation would return null) you are going to have to manually check to see if the "-Select-" is selected then insert null value to the database with a simple ternary if or however pleases you. but how are you adding items to the dropdown??

Comment: well then you are going to have to insert null values manually as Bishnu Paudel suggested

Answer (score 0):

You have to check at insert time `dropdownlist`select item is equal to `-SELECT-` then you have to insert value `null` in your `database`

```
if(dropdownlist1.SelectedItem.Text == "-SELECT-")
{
   // set your database value null here 
}
```

Comment: // set your database value null here, 
how?

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code..

```
string drpvalue=DropDown1.SelectedIndex==0?System.DBNull.Value:DropDown1.SelectedValue
```

Then insert `drpvalue` into Database